# firebase is not letting me store more than X characters in realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to store Apple receipt information in firebase but it's too long and the database truncates the characters. How can I store large amounts of information in firebase realtime database?

Comment: [A single node can store 10Mb of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#data_tree)... And I am pretty sure you data isn't that long/big. Can you provide more information about what you are doing and include code snippet and some example data?

Comment: I’m talking about a specific field. I’m have a json object with specific properties. Each property can’t be too long.

Comment: Firebase doesn't have JSON 'objects' as such. It uses JSON structure to store your data in parent and child nodes. Each specific field, known as a node or a child node in Firebase, can house 10Mb. Keys can be up to 768k but if you are talking field - that's 10Mb of data - which could be a 10Mb string for example. That would be approximately equal to a 2.5Mb ASCII string - that's (1Mb = 125,000 bytes) 312,500 characters of text (Firebase data data is UTF-8 encoded so it's 1 byte to 4 UTF-8 byte ratio, roughly). So it may not be the receipt causing the issue but something else in your code.